# How to find the path of the uploaded files on Weebly?

Tags: java, html, path, applet

I'm trying to make my own website using Weebly. I want to include a Java Applet I made and therefore I must use an HTML snippet on the website. In the snippet I have to include the path of my uploaded Applet in order for it to run. How can I get this path, because I do not know where the files end up after uploading them. I saw in one post that each user gets a very specific path with each upload but how did they find this out? Is there a way?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it now. I'm relatively new to the community so I had to do a little reading before I figured out what it means and how could I improve it. Do you know the answer to my question or can you direct me to someone who does?

Comment: This [Weebly](http://www.weebly.com/)? I'd never heard of it before I (actually) read your question a few moments ago.  What is the link of the 'one post'?  As it stands, I doubt anyone here could answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weebly by default gives it's subdomain sites the ability to control content so when you upload anything to weebly via Code Editor (Weebly main -> Design -> Edit Html/CSS -> Add New Files)
the default address is

```
yoursubdomain.weebly.com/files/theme/filename.extension
```

For example if my file name is social-grey and is png extension and my subdomain is geniusknight ( http://geniusknight.weebly.com ) then the link would be:

```
geniusknight.weebly.com/files/theme/social-grey.png
```

Similarly for Javascript extension with name test would be

```
http://geniusknight.weebly.com/files/theme/test.js
```

and make sure in the source use the complete url and not the short ones like test.js because that doesn't work in subdomain sites for weebly.

Comment: If the image is in an "images" subfolder, the path will be /files/theme/images/imageName.png. One could use // instead of http to ensure compatibility with https.

Answer (score 3):

not sure if you still need an answer to this....the path for uploaded files into your weebly site (via the Design Tab, then "edit HTML/CSS" menu is "/files/theme/yourfilename.js"

Answer (score 1):

Go to Design > Edit HTML/CSS > Assets folder.

Go to the image or file you'd like to reference and grab the URL.

e.g. http://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/3/4/0/9/34091/custom_themes/647127941726820885/files/homelogos/codehs.jpg

To use a relative path instead of an absolute path, remove everything before /uploads...

e.g. /uploads/3/4/0/9/34091/custom_themes/647127941726820885/files/homelogos/codehs.jpg

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Weebly` then design and edit `html`.

Left click a pre existing `.png` image, then in that same window right click over the image that pops up and go to open image in new tab.

In the new tab you will see the address in the address bar. It will look something like this...

`weebly.com/uploads/6/9/2/1/12851110/custom_themes/138585217722419571/files/yilogo.rar?1407684265479`

You can drop the `?1407684265479` bit to have a direct `url` for your file!!!!

`weebly.com/uploads/6/9/2/1/12851110/custom_themes/138585217722419571/files/yilogo.rar`

Then replace that file name in this case `yilogo.rar` with the file you have just uploaded or wish to use from your existing collection. E.g.

`weebly.com/uploads/6/9/2/1/12851110/custom_themes/138585217722419571/files/flags.exe`